# modify specific item in c++ vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I would like to keep track of one item in a vector and modify it as follows:

```
vector<myObj> v;

myObj obj = myObj(params)
v.push_back(myObj);

obj = myObj(params)
v.push_back(myObj);

obj = myObj(params)
v.push_back(myObj);

myObj* modThis = &v[2];
//modify modThis
```

but when I do something like this in my real code, it only modifies a copy of the object instead of modifying the actual object inside the vector. I printed the addresses of modThis and of &v[2] and they are NOT the same! I have also tried something like the following:

```
myObj modThis = v[2]; 
//modiy myObj
```

which also only seems to create a copy of the object and continue to modify the copy but not the original object stored in the vector.

How do I get access to modification of the object inside the vector without copying the item? What am I missing?

Note: myObj currently has the compiler generated copy constructor.

Comment: When you compared addresses did you print `modThis` or `&modThis`?

Comment: I printed modThis and &v[2] and they were not the same.

Comment: `v.push_back(myObj);` won't compile. Please provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce it.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3a7b51ac030c98a) with a suitable [mcve].

Comment: Are you, by any chance, adding elements to or removing them from the vector after saving `&v[2]` in `modThis`? Those operations invalidate some or all pointers, references and iterators to the elements of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with **vector reference operators** in order to modify objects inside your array.
The Correct way:

`vec.at(1).SetString("Modified string");`

If your vector is holding pointers then:

`vec.at(1)->SetString("Modified string");`

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there a difference between: 

    `vec.at(1).SetString("mod"); `

and
    `vec.[1].SetString("mod"); `

they are the same, no?

Comment: They are the same. In both cases you are holding a reference to the object in the array, and you are directly manipulating this object.